# How to add a JSON value read from a parent JSON in a table column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, jsondb

I'm trying to read a JSON and insert the values into a table. Among those values, there is one another JSON object. I'm trying to insert that JSON value into a column, but my code inserts nothing.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp

DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[
  {"id": 2, "info": {"name": "John", "surname": "Smith"}, "age": 25},
  {"id": 5, "info": {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith"}, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00"}
]';

SELECT [id], [info] 
INTO #tmp
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
     WITH
         (
          [id] NVARCHAR(100), 
          [info] NVARCHAR(max)
         );

SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

This is the result I get:

```
id  info
--------------
2   NULL
5   NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to use `AS JSON` option as is mentioned in the documentation:

> Use the AS JSON option in a column definition to specify that the
>   referenced property contains an inner JSON object or array. If you
>   specify the AS JSON option, the type of the column must be
>   NVARCHAR(MAX).

Statement:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[
  {"id": 2, "info": {"name": "John", "surname": "Smith"}, "age": 25},
  {"id": 5, "info": {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith"}, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00"}
]';

SELECT [id], [info] 
INTO #tmp
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
  [id] NVARCHAR(100) '$.id', 
  [info] NVARCHAR(max) '$.info' AS JSON
);
```

Result:

```
id  info
2   {"name": "John", "surname": "Smith"}
5   {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith"}
```

Comment: One problem I'm facing is that it's adding spaces for my actual data. Is there a way to remove those spaces? Other than that thanks, it solved the problem

Comment: @Araf Where are the spaces?

Comment: like { ................. "name":"Josn", "surname": "Smith" .................}, after the brackets (i'm using dots to show space cause stack overflow deletes spaces)